# Difference between pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
int array[10];              
int main  (){
    int *data_ptr;
    int value;

    data_ptr = &array[0];

    value = *data_ptr++;        
    value = *++data_ptr;        
    value = ++*data_ptr;

   return 0;
}
```

Which is the difference between each assignment?

If I print after each value assignment it returns

```
0

0

1
```

Comment: http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~cs240/misc/operators.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
value = *data_ptr++;
```

This assigns the result of dereferencing `data_ptr` to `value`, and then increments `data_ptr`. So the first element of the array, which is 0, will be in `value`, and `data_ptr` will point at the second. This is because `++` has a higher precedence so that it applies to `data_ptr`, not to `*data_ptr`.

```
value = *++data_ptr;
```

This first increments `data_ptr` (so it points at the third element of the array instead of the second, in this case) and then stores the result of dereferencing that (that is, the third element of the array, which is also 0) in `value`.

```
value = ++*data_ptr;
```

This stores the result of dereferencing `data_ptr` (the third element of the array) + 1 (so, 1 in total, as all of the elements of your array are auto-initialised to 0 in this case) in `value`.

Answer (score 0):

well

```
// Increment data_ptr and return the *original* value, then dereference that.
value = *data_ptr++;
// Increment data_ptr and return the new value, then dereference that
value = *++data_ptr;
// Dereference data_ptr then increment the result and return
// the newly incremented value.
value = ++*data_ptr;
```

To make this clear, here's the same thing written out long hand

```
//1
data_ptr+=1;
int* prev = data_ptr - 1;
value = *prev;
//2
data_ptr += 1;
value = *data_ptr;
//3
value = *data_ptr;
value+=1;
```

Comment: A post-increment operator does make a copy, but yes both work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks right to me. The global `array[]` is initialized to zeros. The first `value = *data_ptr` gets the value of a[0], then increments the pointer. The next line increments the pointer again, and so gets a[2]. The last line gets a[2], then increments the value, giving 1.